# Generate GCP table from Geo-referenced raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've Geo-referenced raster, Is there is any way to extract it's GCP table in QGIS ?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "I've Geo-referenced raster"? Have you georeferenced your raster by yourself of have you received the raster somewhere as already georeferenced?

Answer (score 2):

In the Georeferencer tool, there's a button to save the ground control points.

[image]

Even if you didn't save the GCP points while the Georeferencer was open, they should be saved "in a separate text file ([filename].points) usually together with the raster image." (source: [QGIS Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html#entering-ground-control-points-gcps))

Eg, I recently georeferenced a raster, and saved it as "Roadmap_modified.tif". Even though I didn't save the GCP points, there's a file called "Roadmap_modified.tif.points" in the same file as the georeferenced raster.

Comment: I don't have *.points file !

Comment: That's unfortunate. The manual does say that the GCP are *usually* saved together with the raster image. That implies they might be saved somewhere else, so you could try searching your computer for a *.points file. Other than that, I don't have any more suggestions.