# Adding additional points to GCP table after an image has been georeferenced

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have finished georeferencing an image with no attached coordinate system. I was unsatisfied as the image was not accurately overlayed on the map. The dx/dy & Residual error values are not significantly high indicating that there was no human error in the georeferencing process.

I am trying to re-open the GCP table to add more points, however, I have been unable to find a way to do this. The only solution I can think of is to re-do  the  georeferencing. Is there a way to re-open the GCP table to add more points?

Version: QGIS 3.6 
Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: I think you will have to re-georeference the raster, but you *might* be able to retrieve the GCP table so you don't have to start over. Have a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/328547/81764